# The mean and variance of the inverse of a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

I would want to ask if I have a random variable $A \sim N(b,c)$ then what is the distribution of the inverse of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution) and this [math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution), $1 / A$ has a bimodal distribution.

However, the mean and the variance and higher order moments of $1 / A$ are not defined (as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution) for the mean).

Comment: Surely you mean bimodal and not binomial

Comment: (+1) Wikipedia asserts bimodality only for the case $b=0$ and $c=1$.  Clearly the value of $c$ will not affect this characteristic, but in principle $b$ can.  Nevertheless, $1/A$ will always be bimodal, because it has a density of $0$ at $0$ and both the positive and negative parts are unimodal (as becomes obvious when you consider the distribution of their logarithms).